# Token Creation on Ethereum

Tags: tokens

Dear valuable partners,

I am crypto-fun, not an expert. From and living in Benin.

I want to create my own cryptocoin on Ethereum Blockchain. Below are my questions about that:

1. How can I proceed?
2. How much shall I spend for in total?
3. Is it possible to hire Crypto-Techo Experts to help me ? For how
   much?
4. May you provide me with a full PDF documentation about all the
   procedures?

THANKS SO MUCH

Comment: Very broad question. I'd look into ERC20 tokens (there is plenty of material on this site), then enquire on linkedin for blockchain developers. They'll only be able to discuss their rate with you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very broad question, but I'll try to answer the questions, though.

> I want to create my own cryptocoin on Ethereum Blockchain. Below are
>   my questions about that:
>
> How can I proceed?

I'd recommend you start looking into articles that explain the whole dynamic around doing an ICO / Token Crowdsale. There's many things you have to take into account and the actual coding is only a part of it.
There's a lot of excellent primers on Medium. Here are a few of them:

- https://steemit.com/steemit/@belidged/a-guide-on-how-to-ico
- https://hackernoon.com/the-ico-handbook-705a89fa8978
- http://startupmanagement.org/2017/09/11/safe-ico-practices-sip/

> How much shall I spend for in total?

Hard to tell. I've been involved in ICOs that costed $500k and upwards and I have friends/acquittances that have spent more than $1mm between legal fees, developers, community managers, PR experts, technical writer, project lead, etc, etc. It also depends on how much money you are trying to raise. The bigger the ICO the more expensive it becomes.

> Is it possible to hire Crypto-Techo Experts to help me ? For how much?

Yes, of course. There's many people willing to offer their services to help you launch an ICO. What you have to understand is that doing an ICO not only requires a Solidity developer to code the smart contracts, but it also requires the same or even more work than raising funds in the traditional way. You have to build the right team, communicate your vision properly, build a community, do a lot of research, pitch to investors, etc, etc.

I recommend you approach people on LinkedIn and you could also try posting on Reddit, but generally, people with no technical skills and a "great idea" are frowned upon in these communities.

> May you provide me with a full PDF documentation about all the
>   procedures?

Not really. There's no "full PDF documentation" on how to do an ICO. It's very novel and people are still learning the ropes. You can get started with the articles I shared and search for a lot more of them on Medium written by other people that share their own experiences.